# Reverse Survivorship Bias

Tags: bias

**Goal:**

I have **car accident data** with geo-positions and would like to create a model to predict hotspots due to specific influence factors or features.

**Problem:**

To validate the results I want to create a test-set but since I only have accidents and no samples for accident-free car rides I thought about creating them artificially.
Unfortunately, I have no data of traffic density for specific roads.

**Current Approach:**

Therefore I thought about two ways of approaching this:

1. Use the geo-position of occured accidents and pick other features randomly to keep the distribution intact.
2. Create Random samples on random geo-positions (within road-network) with random features.

**Question:**

Is there a way to create artifical samples for this in a way which introduces less bias?